# Can anyone help me with this indefinite integral?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Couldn't solve this indefinite integral, can someone help me?  $$\int \frac {x^3+4x^2+6x+1}{x^3+x^2+x-3} dx$$

Comment: Do long division, factorise the denominator and do partial fractions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, do long division to change your improper rational expression into a polynomial plus a proper rational expression.  $$\int 1 +\frac{3x^2+5x+4}{x^3+x^2+x-3} \; dx.$$  Then factor the denominator by noting that if you plug in $x=1$ you get $0$, so $x-1$ is a factor.  Then do partial fractions to get $$\int 1 + \frac{2}{x-1} + \frac{x+2}{x^2+2x+3} \; dx.$$  Finally, complete the square in the quadratic to get $$\frac{(x+1)+1}{(x+1)^2+2}$$ and substitute $u=x+1$.  That leaves $$\int 1 \;dx + \int \frac{2}{x-1} \; dx + \int \frac{u}{u^2+2} \; du + \int \frac{1}{u^2+2} \; du.$$

Comment: Fixed it.  (Heck, it was $t$ the first time.)

Comment: Np...such mistakes happens to us all :)

Answer (score 2):

$$x^3+4x^2+6x+1=(x^3+x^2+x-3)+3x^2+5x+4$$
Thus,
$$\int\frac{x^3+4x^2+6x+1}{x^3+x^2+x-3}dx=\int\left(1+\frac{3x^2+5x+4}{x^3+x^2+x-3}\right)dx=\int\left(1+\frac{3x^2+5x+4}{(x-1)(x^2+2x+3)}\right)dx$$

Let
$$\frac{3x^2+5x+4}{(x-1)(x^2+2x+3)}=\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+2x+3}$$

Find A,B, and C and solve.